# Can I use one table column value as another table table name in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to build query like this ->

```
select table1.colname,(select count(*) from table1.colname) As count from table1;
```

Is it possible in mysql?

Please help me..

Comment: Why you do not try it out?

Comment: I have already tried but i am getting table1.colname is doesn't exist.. error

Comment: Your query syntax looks good, check if exists `colname` column in `table1` table if you get this error

Comment: i have to use first table column value as another table name..

Comment: select employee.dept,(select count(*) from employee.dept) as count from employee

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html), something like this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure()
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  declare table_name varchar(50);

  DECLARE cur_input CURSOR FOR select table1.colname from table1;
    OPEN cur_input;
    loop1:loop FETCH cur_input INTO table_name;

    select table_name,(select count(*) from table_name) As count from table1;

    END loop loop1; 

END;
```